# Combining like rows in Excel to show when a classroom is available

Tags: excel

I work in higher education and need to create a schedule that shows when a classroom is being occupied. Here is an example of what I am wanting to combine:

[image]

I want to have one row for each classroom. Is there a way to do this? I can supply the raw data if necessary.

Comment: Please supply data. An outside link is uncomfortable and might become unavailable in the future, making this question useless for other users.

Comment: So you're essentially trying to combine the X's in both rows into one for BUS 105 (in your example)?

Comment: Can you also give an example of the desired output from your example data?

Comment: TMH8885 - Yes. That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth considering [SUBTOTAL](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-subtotal-function).

Assuming `Bldg+Room` is in A1 and ColumnA is sorted by codes, select ColumnsA:AS, DATA > Outline - Subtotal, At each change in: `Bldg+Room`, Use function: Count, Add subtotal to: check boxes for columnsE>suit, Replace current subtotals, Summary below data, OK.

If you then click on the small `2` at the top left you should see a single row, but click on 3 and that should show the detail.

At step further might be to apply Conditional Formatting to values other than `0` in the 'Count' rows.